# SQL: consulta multi tabla kardex

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, select, mysqldb

trato de hacer una consulta SELECT que me retorne valores de estas tablas

[image: tablas]

MI CONSULTA SQL ES LA SIGUIENTE trato que en Stock se sume y reste la cantidad emitidas en compras y ventas :

```
set @TOTAL:=0;

SELECT venta.fecha_hora,"Venta" as tipo, 
CASE 
WHEN ( tipo="venta" ) THEN @TOTAL:= @TOTAL - sum(detalle_venta.cantidad) 
END AS stock, detalle_venta.cantidad, detalle_venta.precio_venta 
FROM articulo, detalle_venta, venta 
WHERE articulo.idarticulo=detalle_venta.idarticulo and detalle_venta.idventa=venta.idventa and articulo.idarticulo="1" 
GROUP BY fecha_hora 

UNION 

SELECT ingreso.fecha_hora,"Compra" as tipo, 
CASE 
WHEN ( tipo="compra" ) THEN @TOTAL:= @TOTAL + sum(detalle_ingreso.cantidad) 
END AS stock, detalle_ingreso.cantidad, detalle_ingreso.precio_compra FROM articulo, detalle_ingreso, ingreso 
WHERE articulo.idarticulo=detalle_ingreso.idarticulo and detalle_ingreso.idingreso=ingreso.idingreso and articulo.idarticulo=1 
GROUP BY fecha_hora 


ORDER BY fecha_hora ASC;
```

RECIBO ESTOS DATOS:

```
fecha_hora Ascendente 1     tipo    stock   cantidad    precio_venta    
2021-12-06 00:00:00        Compra    18      20        5.00
2021-12-11 00:00:00        Compra    18      20        5.00
2021-12-13 00:00:00        Venta     5       -5        2.00
2021-12-15 00:00:00        Compra    48      50        55.00
2021-12-29 00:00:00        Venta     2       -2        2.00
```

PERO LO QUE BUSCO OBTENER ES ESTO:

```
fecha_hora Ascendente 1     tipo    stock   cantidad    precio_venta    
2021-12-06 00:00:00        Compra    20      20        5.00
2021-12-11 00:00:00        Compra    40      20        5.00
2021-12-13 00:00:00        Venta     35      -5        2.00
2021-12-15 00:00:00        Compra    85      50        55.00
2021-12-29 00:00:00        Venta     83      -2        2.00
```